# ¿Cómo trabajar con rango de fechas con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

La idea es que cuando la fecha esté entre el rango realice un `display block` y si se sale del rango haga un `display none`. ya que con el codigo actual solo hace darle display dia comnienza hasta que termina

Lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
(function () {
  let etiqueta = document.getElementById("Evento");
  let fecha = new Date("Oct 8, 2020");
  const fecha_actual = fecha.toLocaleDateString("es-MX", { timeZone: "America/Santiago" });
  const diadelevento = new Date("Oct 7, 2020"); // Cuando empieza el Evento
  const findelevento = new Date("Oct 13, 2020"); // cuando Termina el Evento
  //
  const fecha_inicio = diadelevento.toLocaleDateString("es-MX", { timeZone: "America/Santiago" });
  const fecha_fin = findelevento.toLocaleDateString("es-MX", { timeZone: "America/Santiago" });
  //
  if (fecha_actual == fecha_inicio) {
    etiqueta.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    etiqueta.style.display = "none";
  }
})();
```

Comment: if (fecha_actual>=fecha_inicio && fecha_actual<=fecha_fin)
Esto sería un verificación de rango de fecha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debes comparar las *strings*, sino directamente los valores *Date*; ten en cuenta que en JavaScript no puedes comparar a igual dos fechas (`===`), pero sí diferencias (`>=`, `<=`):

```
if (fecha >= diadelevento && fecha <= findelevento) {
  etiqueta.style.display = "block";
} else {
  etiqueta.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: consulta  como  hago para poner el parametro de  timezone sin strings?